How to reinstall all Google Play Store dependencies, specifically Google Account Manager to make the Play Store work again?
I'm using GNU/Linux and the adb command connected on a Samsung phone (specifically the SM-N9600 model, on Android version 10) without root, and also termux to find paths easily on the phone. I uninstalled Google Account Manager with pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.gsf.login, I think, if I remember correctly.
I cannot get it back with either

pm install-existing com.google.android.gsf.login
pm install -r /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25.apk

I tried looking inside the /system/priv-apps/ directory to find Google Account Manager, but couldn't find it.
When I open the Google Play Store (still haven't made an account on the phone) and press the "Sign In" button, it 'errors out' with this message

Something went wrong
There was a problem communicating with Google servers.
Try again later.


The output of what I have tried so far:

With pm install-existing com.google.android.gsf.login -> https://pastebin.com/h9cJz08z

crownqltechn:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ pm install-existing com.google.android.gsf.login
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Package com.google.android.gsf.login doesn't exist
1|crownqltechn:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ pm install-existing com.google.android.gsf                                                                      
Package com.google.android.gsf installed for user: 0
crownqltechn:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ 


With pm install -r /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25.apk -> https://pastebin.com/bt8JFGJD

crownqltechn:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ ls | grep -i "google"                                                                                             
Google_Account_Manager_v7.1.2.apk
com.google.android.gsf.login_5.1-1743759-22_minAPI21(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk
com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk
crownqltechn:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ pm install -r com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk                           
System server has no access to read file context u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 (from path /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk, context u:r:system_server:s0)
Error: Unable to open file: com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk
Consider using a file under /data/local/tmp/
Error: Can't open file: com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk
 
Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Can't open file: com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:461)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1060)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:169)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:27148)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:916)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:790)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5452)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5158)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1056)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1029)
255|crownqltechn:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ exit
[dream@headstone ~]$ adb install Downloads/com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk 
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install Downloads/com.google.android.gsf.login_7.1.2-25_minAPI23(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Unknown Reason]
[dream@headstone ~]$ 


with ls /system/priv-app/ -> https://pastebin.com/MmYti96x

crownqltechn:/system/priv-app $ ls | grep -i google
GoogleExtServicesPrebuilt
GoogleFeedback
GoogleOneTimeInitializer
GooglePackageInstaller
GooglePartnerSetup
GooglePermissionControllerPrebuilt
GoogleRestore
GoogleServicesFramework
HotwordEnrollmentOKGoogleExWCD9340
HotwordEnrollmentXGoogleExWCD9340
crownqltechn:/system/priv-app $ ls | grep -i account                                                                                                          
SamsungAccount
crownqltechn:/system/priv-app $ #now the entire directory 
crownqltechn:/system/priv-app $ ls -a
.                                Fmm                                OMCAgent5                         SendHelpMessage                
..                               FotaAgent                          ONS                               SettingsBixby                  
ANTRadioService                  FusedLocation                      OmaCP                             SettingsProvider               
AODService_v50                   GalaxyAppsWidget_Phone_Dream       OneDrive_Samsung_v3               SettingsReceiver               
AREmoji                          GalaxyApps_OPEN                    PaymentFramework                  SetupWizard                    
Accessibility                    GameHome                           PeopleStripe                      ShareLive                      
AirCommand                       GameOptimizingService              PhoneErrService                   SharedStorageBackup            
AirReadingGlass                  GameTools_Dream                    Phonesky                          Shell                          
AndroidAutoStub                  GearVRService                      PhotoEditor_Q3_Mid                SingleOutFocusViewer_Q         
AppsEdgePanel_v3.2               GmsCore                            PlatformNetworkPermissionConfig   SingleTakeService              
AssistantMenu_N                  GoogleExtServicesPrebuilt          PowerPoint_SamsungStub            SmartCallProvider              
AuthFramework                    GoogleFeedback                     PreloadInstaller                  SmartEpdgTestApp               
BackupRestoreConfirmation        GoogleOneTimeInitializer           ProxyHandler                      SmartEye                       
BadgeProvider_N                  GooglePackageInstaller             Quickboard                        SmartManager_v5                
BeaconManager                    GooglePartnerSetup                 RubinVersion25                    SmartManager_v6_DeviceSecurity 
BioFaceService                   GooglePermissionControllerPrebuilt SDMConfig                         SmartSwitchAssistant           
BiometricSetting                 GoogleRestore                      SEMFactoryApp                     SoterSskdsSerivce              
Bixby                            GoogleServicesFramework            SKMSAgent                         SoundAlive_70                  
BixbyAgentStub                   HealthService                      SOAgent                           StatementService               
BixbyService                     Hearingdro_Q                       SPPPushClient                     StickerCenter                  
BlockedNumberProvider            HotwordEnrollmentOKGoogleExWCD9340 SVCAgent                          StickerFaceARAvatar            
BlueLightFilter                  HotwordEnrollmentXGoogleExWCD9340  SVoiceIME                         StorageManager                 
CIDManager                       HwModuleTest                       SamsungAccount                    StoryService                   
CMHProvider                      HybridRadio                        SamsungBilling                    SystemUI                       
CSC                              IPService                          SamsungCalendarProvider           SystemUIBixby2                 
CallLogBackup                    ImsLogger                          SamsungCamera                     SystemUIDesktop                
CarrierConfig                    ImsTelephonyService                SamsungCloudClient                Tag                            
ClipboardSaveService             InProcessNetworkStack              SamsungContacts                   TaskEdgePanel_v3.2             
ClipboardUIService               InputDevices                       SamsungContactsMigrator           TeeService                     
CocktailBarService_v3.2          IntelligentBiometricsService       SamsungContactsProvider           TeleService                    
ConfigUpdater                    IpsGeofence                        SamsungDeviceHealthManagerService Telecom                        
ContainerAgent3                  IrisUserTest                       SamsungDialer                     TelephonyUI                    
CtsShimPrivPrebuilt              KLMSAgent                          SamsungExperienceService          ThemeCenter                    
DeXonPC                          KeyguardWallpaperUpdator           SamsungGallery2018                ThemeStore                     
DesktopModeUiService             KnoxCore                           SamsungInCallUI                   TimeZoneData                   
DeviceKeystring                  KnoxDesktopLauncher                SamsungMagnifier3                 Tips                           
DevicePersonalizationServices    KnoxGuard                          SamsungMessages_11                TouchWizHome_2017              
DeviceQualityAgent               KnoxKeyChain                       SamsungMultiConnectivity          Turbo                          
DeviceTest                       LedCoverAppCrown                   SamsungPass                       UIBCVirtualSoftkey             
DiagMonAgent                     LedCoverService                    SamsungPositioning                UserDictionaryProvider         
DigitalWellbeing                 LinkToWindowsService               SamsungSocial                     Velvet                         
DocumentsUI                      LinkedIn_SamsungStub               SamsungTimeZoneUpdater            VpnDialogs                     
DownloadProviderUi               LiveStickers                       SamsungVideoPlayer                WallpaperCropper               
DressRoom                        LocalTransport                     SecCarrierProvider                WallpaperCropper2              
DualOutFocusViewer_Q             ManagedProvisioning                SecDownloadProvider               Word_SamsungStub               
DynamicLockscreen                MateAgent                          SecIrisService                    YourPhone_Stub                 
DynamicSystemInstallationService MediaLearningPlatform              SecLiveWallpapersPicker           com.qualcomm.location          
EasySetup                        MediaProvider                      SecMediaProvider                  imsservice                     
EmergencyInfo                    MmsService                         SecMyFiles2019                    knoxanalyticsagent             
EnhancedAttestationAgent         MobileWips                         SecSettings                       knoxvpnproxyhandler            
EpdgService                      ModemServiceMode                   SecSettingsIntelligence           ringtoneBR                     
Excel_SamsungStub                MtpApplication                     SecSetupWizard_Global             serviceModeApp_FB              
ExternalStorageProvider          MtpDocumentsProvider               SecSoterService                   smartfaceservice               
FBInstaller_NS                   MultiSoundSetting                  SecSoundPicker                    wallpaper-res                  
FBServices                       NSDSWebApp                         SecTelephonyProvider              
FaceService                      NSFusedLocation_v5.0_UPG           SecureFolder                      
Finder                           NetworkDiagnostic                  SelectiveFocusViewer              
crownqltechn:/system/priv-app $ 

Is there any way to 'resurrect' the Google Play Store? Some government apps need the Google Play Store or else they crash.

I would check logcat for a more detailed message of "Something went wrong". May be there are other side-effects.

You coukd try a factory reset

I couldn't find anything with logcat, except:
05-10 16:33:43.403  9951  9951 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
05-10 16:33:43.012  9951 10421 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
which is probably not useful logs...

I may have to backup all my files and factory reset if it's truly impossible.
if I could get root access or a way to mount the android's file system on GNU/Linux with write permissions I'd manually install everything like on LFS but that's not the case...
